# JControllerLegacy getinstance to load controller

Tags: joomla, controller, extension-methods, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

How can I load UsersControllerRegistration using JControllerLegacy getinstance. I know we can load "UserController" using below code

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Users');
```

I want to call register method to register an user from my custom form.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, after reding the JControllerLegacy::getInstance code, it seems that you cannot load that specific controller with that method.

You should just require it and load it:

```
require JPATH_COMPONENT . '/com_users/controllers/registration.php';
$registrationController = new UsersControllerRegistration();
```